# JQuery splice DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to perform a splice method much like the native Array.splice but I would like to splice a jQuery collection of DOM elements. How is this done cleanly?

Edit: why do I need example code? I am looking for the exact same functionality of the ECMAScript Array.splice function, except I want it to work on a jQuery array of DOM elements, and update the DOM when it's done.

Comment: Please provide what you have so far.

Comment: I'm guessing jQuery's own `add()` or `slice()` methods would do that, but it's impossible for us to really help you, as we have no idea what it is you're trying to splice ?

Comment: You need to provide a sample because there are elements that don't make sense. What happens if you try to "splice" the following together [form, iframe, div]. What would you expect this to look like?!

Comment: sure help next time to define if you want to add or remove with `splice` like functionality

Comment: @LeeTaylor there is nothing wrong with mixing tags. See my answer below for a working example (you need to select a jQuery framework in jsFiddle...for some reason that isn't saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting elements with jQuery actually gives you an array of elements, which can be treated as a normal javascript array as well as a jQuery object. To ensure that an array is a jQuery object you can wrap it in a call to `jQuery()`. For example:

```
var x = jQuery('p'),
    y = jQuery(x.splice(x.length / 2, x.length));

x.css('background-color', 'red');
y.css('background-color', 'blue');
```

`x` contains the first half of `<p>` tags, which all now have a red background, and `y` has the second half, with a blue background.

Here's some [proof](http://jsfiddle.net/86mqx/).

Also, there is no problem with mixing tags (e.g. `<p>` and `<div>` tags can be in the array and jQuery will work as expected). See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/86mqx/1/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a DOM collection after splice of your collection you need  reload the DOM with that collection to made effect the changes .

So use append and remove keywords for live changes .. which are equals to splice on an collection.